# How to pass an array of object into a payload in a JSON format while making a api request

Tags: javascript, json, api, payload

I have an array of objects like this.

```
var arr = [
{name: 'myName', age: 25, city: 'myCity'},
{name: 'myName1', age: 25, city: 'myCity1'}
];
```

Now, I need to pass this arr array into a payload as a JSON object.
I used `JSON.stringify(arr)` and then passed the data. But it is getting converted into a form-data and the payload format is like below;

```
[{name: 'myName', age: 25, city: 'myCity'},{name: 'myName1', age: 25, city: 'myCity1'}]:
```

If you have noticed a colon at the end of the payload, seems like it converted my array as a property name to the form data. Can you help me to pass the array as a JSON object.

Code that is used to call the API method is,

```
{
 type: 'POST',
 method: 'POST',
 dataType: 'json',
 url: 'url of the api call',
 beforeSend: function(header, settingsData){
    Object.keys(settingsData.options).forEach(headerKey){
       headerKey.setHeader(headerKey, settingsData.options[headerKey]);
    }
    return settingsData;
 },
 disableDefaultError: true
}
```

Comment: _"But it is getting converted into a form-data"_ - what do you mean? -- _"as a JSON object"_ - no JSON is a string not an object. -- When stringified `arr` does not have a colon at the end.

Comment: payload's data type became form-data instead of json. Thus the content type got assigned to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: It becomes key value pair and thats why we get colon(:) at the end i guess. But how to pass the JSON object in the payload.

Comment: Please share the code used to send the data? It's likely the wrong format is being used.

Comment: I have updated the code above. Please check.

Comment: Please may you make sure the code is a [mcve]? Are you using fetch, axios, etc?

Comment: Should the dataType (content type) for JSON be `application/json` not `json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[My comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70782725/how-to-pass-an-array-of-object-into-a-payload-in-a-json-format-while-making-a-ap/70784499#comment-125135869) was [half correct.](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/)

- Keep `dataType: 'json'`
- add `contentType: 'application/json'` since the default is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`

```
{
 type: 'POST',
 method: 'POST',
 dataType: 'json',
 contentType: 'application/json', // <- this is needed
 url: 'url of the api call',
 beforeSend: function(header, settingsData){
    Object.keys(settingsData.options).forEach(headerKey){
       headerKey.setHeader(headerKey, settingsData.options[headerKey]);
    }
    return settingsData;
 },
 disableDefaultError: true
}
```